# How to visualise generated png images during travis build

Tags: travis-ci

I have a cypress plugin that generate screenshots, is there a way to visualise those generated screenshots after success or failure ?

the screenshots folder path:

```
/home/travis/build/Org/my-app/cypress/snapshots/actual/Visual_testing/Login_page.js/Login page-actual.png
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to access **directly** Travis filesystem.

Also, everything that was generated during the build is destroyed once the build finishes.

If you want to recover the screenshots, you have to move them somewhere else.

Check the following documentation.

[Uploading Artifacts on Travis CI](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/uploading-artifacts/).

> Travis CI can automatically upload your build artifacts to Amazon S3 at the end of the job, after the after_script phase.

You could also upload them to GitHub or whatever you want.

The [Deployment](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/) documentation covers a lot of providers.